# align text in Table row semantic ui to center

Tags: html, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

How can I make text inside a table row in semantic-ui react as center.

I tried this but not working:

```
<Table.Row className='center'>No Records Found</Table.Row>
// the text No Records found appears in the left most side of column.
```

`css`

```
.center{
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: try `<Table.Row><div className="center">No Records</div></Table.Row>`

Comment: You might also need to make the `div` as the same width as the table row

Comment: It should work, check if you already import your styles correctly.

Comment: [Live Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-wmptd?file=/example.js)

Comment: <Table.Body>
          <Table.Row><center>No Records Found</center></Table.Row>
    </Table.Body>